# unable to add element to array

Tags: php, codeigniter, array-push

**Controller**

```
public function category_fetching(){
    $result=$this->AdminModel->category_fetching();
    $arraymaincat=array();   
    $ifarraymatch=""; 
    $result_count=$result[1];  
          for($i=0;$i<$result_count;$i++){
               $uniquemaincat=($result[0][$i])->maincategory;
               if ($arraymaincat=="" && !$uniquemaincat==""){
                  array_push($arraymaincat,$uniquemaincat);
               }
          }
         print_r($arraymaincat);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function category_fetching(){                
            $query=$this->db->get('category');
            $result[0]=$query->result();
            $result[1]=$query->num_rows();
            return $result;
     }
```

when I print_r the $arraymaincat it gives an empty array, in the log I get

```
Array
(
)
```

Comment: ensure that code satisfies the loop as well as if condition. otherwise it will return empty array

Comment: both loop and if conditions are working . whe i print $result_count i get 10, whe i print $uniquemaincat i get 'clothing'.  is there any probelm with the scope of the $arraymaincat , is the changes to $arramaincat not applicable outside the if condition and loop ?

Comment: You have `$arraymaincat==""` - as `$arraymaincat` is an array, not sure what you are trying to achieve with this.

Comment: @Nigel Ren if there is no element in array then push the value to array

Comment: An empty array isn't = `""` - try `$arraymaincat==[]` or use `empty($arraymaincat)`

Comment: @ Nigel Ren thank-you bro, empty($arraymaincat) worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try `if (count($arraymaincat) == 0 && count($uniquemaincat) != 0)`.

Comment: Glad I could help, sir.